# Nodejs mongojs install error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, mongojs

I'm having some problems installing mongojs via npm. Whenever I try to install it (on windows 8) I just get a page full of red errors. There's so many of them that I don't even know where to begin, heres a sample of them (this is maybe 1/10 of total errors):

```
c:\users\simon\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\no
de_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.h(52): error C4430:
 missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (
..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc) [C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\
npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerbe
ros.vcxproj]
c:\users\simon\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\no
de_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.h(47): error C2039:
 'HasInstance' : is not a member of 'v8::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate,v8::No
nCopyablePersistentTraits<T>>' [C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]


c:\users\simon\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\no
de_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.h(52): error C2143:
 syntax error : missing ',' before '&' (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credenti
als.cc) [C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\m
ongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
c:\users\simon\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\no
de_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.h(53): error C4430:
 missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (
..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc) [C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\
npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerbe
ros.vcxproj]
c:\users\simon\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\no
de_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers/security_context.h(53): error C4430: mis
sing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\l
ib\win32\kerberos.cc) [C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\
node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
c:\users\simon\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\no
de_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.h(53): error C2143:
 syntax error : missing ',' before '&' (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credenti
als.cc) [C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\m
ongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
c:\users\simon\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\no
de_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers/security_context.h(53): error C2143: syn
tax error : missing ',' before '&' (..\lib\win32\kerberos.cc) [C:\Users\Simon\A
ppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerbe
ros\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
c:\users\simon\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\no
de_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers/security_context.h(54): error C4430: mis
sing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\l
ib\win32\kerberos.cc) [C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\
node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
c:\users\simon\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\no
de_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers/security_context.h(54): error C2143: syn
tax error : missing ',' before '&' (..\lib\win32\kerberos.cc) [C:\Users\Simon\A
ppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerbe
ros\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
c:\users\simon\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\no
de_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers/security_context.h(56): error C4430: mis
sing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\l
ib\win32\kerberos.cc) [C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\
node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
c:\users\simon\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\no
de_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers/security_context.h(56): error C2143: syn
tax error : missing ',' before '&' (..\lib\win32\kerberos.cc) [C:\Users\Simon\A
ppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerbe
ros\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
c:\users\simon\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\no
de_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.h(60): error C4430:
 missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (
..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc) [C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\
npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerbe
ros.vcxproj]
c:\users\simon\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\no
de_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers/security_context.h(57): error C4430: mis
sing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\l
ib\win32\kerberos.cc) [C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\
node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
c:\users\simon\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\no
de_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.h(60): error C2143:
 syntax error : missing ',' before '&' (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credenti
als.cc) [C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\m
ongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
c:\users\simon\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\no
de_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers/security_context.h(57): error C2143: syn
tax error : missing ',' before '&' (..\lib\win32\kerberos.cc) [C:\Users\Simon\A
ppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerbe
ros\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
c:\users\simon\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\no
de_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers/security_context.h(57): fatal error C100
3: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation (..\lib\win32\kerberos.cc) [C:
\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\node
_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
c:\users\simon\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\no
de_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.h(47): error C2819:
 type 'v8::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate,v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>>'
 does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->' [C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roami
ng\npm\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\ke
rberos.vcxproj]
```

The same type of thing occurs when I try to install mongoose. mongodb native installed ok but had to install visual studio first to get that to work.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not ideal, but I did a fresh reinstall of node and visual studio and things seem to work OK now